# Which megamenu supports i18n content translation?

Tags: i18n-l10n, navigation

Do you know which megamenu supports i18n content translation?

Comment: With Drupal core alone, user-defined menu items are not translatable. The Menu translation module, part of the i18n package, allows users to select a translation mode for each menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time only tb_megamenu seems to support i18n.

Comment: Any research to support this claim?

Comment: I tried it and its working.
Each language has to got own menu.

Comment: But why do you claim "only"?